# How can I filter the object in the List with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I filter the object in the List with Mongoose?

However, I have to reach the Scenario ID in all products at once without sending repeated queries.

There is an error in findAll, it does not allow me to enter the Array.

```
let getItems = await secondModel.findOne({
   item_scenarios.scenario_id: '1'
});
```

Model making is like this.

```
item_scenarios: [
  {
    _id: 6050545060f40107076f2755,
    scenario_id: '1',
    scenario_tree_point: [Array]
  },
  {
    _id: 6050546160f40107076f2756,
    scenario_id: '1',
    scenario_tree_point: [Array]
  },
  {
    _id: 6050549b60f40107076f2757,
    scenario_id: '1',
    scenario_tree_point: [Array]
  },
  {
    _id: 6050698e140a110a11365aad,
    scenario_id: '604f3376dd79d8118a6990fe',
    scenario_tree_point: [Array]
  }
],
```

**Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'**

Comment: Do you mean `model.find()` ?

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is referring to the dot in `item_scenarios.scenario_id`. They are not valid in object keys in JS. Wrapping the key in quotes should fix the error:

```
let getItems = await secondModel.findOne({
   'item_scenarios.scenario_id': '1'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

findOne return the whole document when your condition are met. So use aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      item_scenarios: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$item_scenarios",
          as: "scenario",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$scenario.scenario_id",
              "1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "item_scenarios": [
      {
        "_id": "6050545060f40107076f2755",
        "scenario_id": "1",
        "scenario_tree_point": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "6050546160f40107076f2756",
        "scenario_id": "1",
        "scenario_tree_point": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "6050549b60f40107076f2757",
        "scenario_id": "1",
        "scenario_tree_point": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/OWyOD1HdKFE